# My site does not appear in the first 30 or more Google pages. What could be the reasons?

Tags: seo, google, ranking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

I did this site about 2 months ago: [www.pbg-bulgaria.com](http://pbg-bulgaria.com)
The problem is that I cannot find the site, for keywords such as “bulgarian properties” and related in the first 30 or even more Google pages.

The tool I'm using for Google position says that the site cannot be found in the first 100 pages, which is quite alarming. Google Analytics shows no traffic from generic keywords (only keywords associated with the name of the company)

I know that a lot of improvements can be made: there is no h1 and h2 titles, I don’t have many backlinks yet, I can put some more keywords here and there, but overall I think the site is ok. In the Google Webmaster account everything looks fine as well.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: So you're saying your site has no reason to rank well but are wondering why it doesn't rank well??? Fix your HTML, get your keywords in order, and get some backlinks!!!

Comment: Stop keyword stuffing your page titles. Optimize your site for usability, not SEO. Your page titles are terrible and make the site come off as spammy despite the relatively clean/professional aesthetic design.

Comment: I thought the page titles were fine, but i will surely reconsider them.

Answer (score 1):

having no back links is bad. I suggest you to try to earn some(using non spam methods of course). You can try http://www.woorank.com and check what are your website weak sides that can easily be optimised. Running a web campaign using some advertising tools(such as Add Words) can bring you more visitors too. Also can you tell how old you website is? If it is fairly new this may also have some impact. Optimize your titles and wait for a while. Building a famous website is not a one day task.

P.S. If you use my advice and test it with woorank A nice point to start with is to resolve the "www" problem. If you have problems with any of these just ask.

Comment: That's a very useful tool, didn't know it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think back links are the most important thing you need to worry about. I recently launched a website, and one of the things I did was try and get links posted to it. For example, on sites such as stackoverflow, you can update your user info to include a link to your website.

Another thing I did was find relevant blog posts about the solutions I offer and post comments on the blog post which could help users. You need to make sure to not make your posts appear like spam. You should genuinely be interested in helping people solve the problem they have, and create a solution that is good enough to be able to link to it in blog post comments. People should find your comment to be useful and not a shameless plug.

Another benefit of adding comments on blog posts is that they usually allow you to add a website link, similar to stackoverflow, which is yet another link to your site.

Comment: StackOverflow only gives you the opportunity to create a nonfollow link. The same is true for most blogs as well.

Comment: Christian is right, these things can bring you visitors but I doubt they will increase your pagerank.

Answer (score 1):

On another topic, your HTML doesn't validate either!  I'm a firm believer that quality (standards-compliant) code is the first step to a quality site.  You gotta start somewhere....

There's a lot that goes into quality SEO, and there's no single right answer.  Being a veteran of numerous Realtor-focused websites, I can tell you that SEO is a nightmare because as a group they are in cutthroat competition with their peers.  With ridiculous advertising budgets and an army of SEO-focused companies helping them, some established realtor sites can gum up several of the top spots on their own.  In my market, getting a site in the top 100 results upon launch would be quite a coup.

Answer (score 0):

A simple thing to test is to run the SEO Toolkit from MS. It is free and can be installed from the Web platform installer. Getting people to link to your site is harder but if you provide a good service a market it well they will soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have enough back links (quality links not just quantity), it's quite normal not to rank high in search engine result pages (SERPs), and this is regardless of how good and relevant your content is. It's sad but true.

As your site is new, it also might be the [sandbox effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_effect) (although this has never been confirmed by google).

Answer (score 0):

Nobody mentioned the **domain name** yet...?

Look again at the SERP for 'bulgarian properties' on google.
**SERP 1 is bulgarianproperties.com**  surprise surprise...
and SERP 2 is whichbulgarianproperties.com
Do you see a pattern?
Do you see anything in bold in the google SERPs?

The domain name on a 2 words keyword search is the most important parameter...

Grab yourself a domain name **bulgarianproperties.something** (it's ok to use .hm, .cc, etc).
Extension is not so important as long as you have **EXACTLY 'bulgarianproperties'** in your domain name.

Once you have this domain, set up your site.. get it indexed... **wait three months** and you should be in the top page.... unless it's a really competitive market.
If it is too competitive **find a niche**: check Google Adwords keyword tool or SEMRush.com,
and look for keywords that are searched less -> usually if you can get the **exact keyword match + .com** that's a very good site you can corner the market and be SERP 1 in google.

Oh and make sure to also have an exact match on the TITLE of your main page.

Best of luck.

Comment: I am not so sure that the domain itself have so much weight as search criteria, so I started another question on the topic how important the domain name is on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3548/how-important-is-the-domain-name-for-seo if you like it, please answer and share your experience with us